# client specific settings in bind9

Tags: bind9

I am using Bind9 as a DNS server in my home network. Furthermore I use a response-policy-zone to block some specific domains and addresses (A to 127.0.0.1).

Is it possible to specify such a "blacklist" only for one specific client. So in general: does Bind9 support client specific overriding/name-resolving?

best regards,
spigandromeda

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.10.3-P4/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#view_statement_grammar) to create client-specific zone resolution in BIND.

> The view statement is a powerful feature of BIND 9 that lets a name
>   server answer a DNS query differently depending on who is asking. It
>   is particularly useful for implementing split DNS setups without
>   having to run multiple servers.
>
> Each view statement defines a view of the DNS namespace that will be
>   seen by a subset of clients. A client matches a view if its source IP
>   address matches the address_match_list of the view's match-clients
>   clause and its destination IP address matches the address_match_list
>   of the view's match-destinations clause. If not specified, both
>   match-clients and match-destinations default to matching all
>   addresses. In addition to checking IP addresses match-clients and
>   match-destinations can also take keys which provide an mechanism for
>   the client to select the view. A view can also be specified as
>   match-recursive-only, which means that only recursive requests from
>   matching clients will match that view. The order of the view
>   statements is significant — a client request will be resolved in the
>   context of the first view that it matches.
>
> Zones defined within a view statement will only be accessible to
>   clients that match the view. By defining a zone of the same name in
>   multiple views, different zone data can be given to different clients,
>   for example, "internal" and "external" clients in a split DNS setup.
>
> Many of the options given in the options statement can also be used
>   within a view statement, and then apply only when resolving queries
>   with that view. When no view-specific value is given, the value in the
>   options statement is used as a default. Also, zone options can have
>   default values specified in the view statement; these view-specific
>   defaults take precedence over those in the options statement.
>
> Views are class specific. If no class is given, class IN is assumed.
>   Note that all non-IN views must contain a hint zone, since only the IN
>   class has compiled-in default hints.
>
> If there are no view statements in the config file, a default view
>   that matches any client is automatically created in class IN. Any zone
>   statements specified on the top level of the configuration file are
>   considered to be part of this default view, and the options statement
>   will apply to the default view. If any explicit view statements are
>   present, all zone statements must occur inside view statements.